# compare values in multiple columns and add the column name that has a distinct value to another column in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns, distinct-values, rowwise

I want to evaluate the values in multiple columns (row-wise) and find out the column name with a different value (unique or numeric-wise) than the other ones and write that name to another column.

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  colA = as.integer(c(1,-1,1,1,-1)),
  colB = as.integer(c(-1,1,1,-1,1)),
  colC = as.integer(c(1,1,1,-1,-1)),
  colD = as.integer(c(1,1,-1,-1,-1)))

Output:

  colA colB colC colD
1    1   -1    1    1
2   -1    1    1    1
3    1    1    1   -1
4    1   -1   -1   -1
5   -1    1   -1   -1
```

Is there a quick (and preferred in base-R) way to check which column has a different value than the others and write the name of that column to another column? The desired output would look like this:

```
  colA colB colC colD results
1    1   -1    1    1    colB
2   -1    1    1    1    colA
3    1    1    1   -1    colD
4    1   -1   -1   -1    colA
5   -1    1   -1   -1    colB
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` + `purrr` option might be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(results = pmap_chr(across(everything()), 
                           ~ names(c(...)[which(ave(c(...), c(...), FUN = length) == 1)])))

  colA colB colC colD results
1    1   -1    1    1    colB
2   -1    1    1    1    colA
3    1    1    1   -1    colD
4    1   -1   -1   -1    colA
5   -1    1   -1   -1    colB
```

Or with just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(results = names(cur_data())[which(ave(c_across(everything()), c_across(everything()), FUN = length) == 1)])
```